# How to save Pytorch tensor attributes to disk?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, getattr, setattr

I used `setattr` to save some information with a Pytorch Tensor, which can be retrieved as expected:

```
import torch
before_write = torch.Tensor()
setattr(before_write, "features", "my_features")
print(before_write.features)
> 'my_features'
```

Unexpectedly, when I write the tensor to disk, and then read it back in again, the features have disappeared:

```
torch.save(before_write, "~/my_tensor")
after_write = torch.load("~/my_tensor")
print(after_write.features)
> AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'features'
```

Why is the attribute lost when writing the tensor to disk? Is this expected behaviour? Would there be a workaround to save the features together with the tensor?

NB: using an empty Python class and writing it with pickle, *does* retain the attributes.

Comment: Have you tried unpickling the saved tensor using `pickle.load()` instead of `torch.load()`? The `torch.load()` function is documented to have some extra behaviour beyond basic unpickling and it seems likely the attribute gets lost there? https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=save#torch.load

Comment: @Grismar: I don't think it makes sense to `pickle.load()` the torch object, right? But I did try to `pickle.dump()` and then read back in with `pickle.load()`, resulting in the same error.

Comment: judging from the similarity in the serialized representation as shown via `pickle.dumps()` of a tensor with and without a large attribute, it seems that tensor attributes are just not serialized. That leaves question 2 and 3 then...

Comment: The reason I thought it made sense is because the documentation for `torch.load()` states that it's using `pickle` (with specific settings), so I figured there might be a clue there whether the unpickling is the problem, or whether the specific settings for `pickle` cause the issue.